# Retain line number after parsing YAML to JSON

Tags: java, gson, snakeyaml

I receive a YAML file which I parse using snakeyaml-engine(for YAML 1.2).

```
LoadSettings settings = new LoadSettingsBuilder().build();
Load load = new Load(settings);
Map<String, Object> yamlMap = (Map<String, Object>) load.loadFromString(new String(<yaml_contents_as_byte_array>));
```

I then use GSON to convert this into a JsonObject.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(gson.toJson(yamlMap)).getAsJsonObject();
```

The goal is to run through this YAML, checking it against a known data model. If fields differ, required fields are missing, etc. I must return an error for each one. The goal is to find some way to include the line number of the problem field from the original YAML, but as I am doing my validations via JSON, I do not know the original line number when I run into an error. I am curious if there is some straightforward way to persist the line number of the YAML, perhaps by adding a lineNumber/columnNumber value to each field as it is parsed and inserted into the map?

Answer (score 0):

A distinct non-answer: I am not aware of any build in mechanism that you could use here. So you probably have to write code yourself to achieve to do both things:

- keep track of yaml properties together with line numbers
- enhance the corresponding Json beans with line number fields

But honestly, the real answer (imho): have distinct validation code that can work on either yaml or Json input "directly". That additional conversion for the purpose of validation, I find that highly doubtful.